# R - countifs like excel

Tags: r

I have a CSV like this, saved as an object in R named df1.

```
 X Y Z Year
 0 2 4 2014
 3 1 3 2014
 5 4 0 2014
 0 3 0 2014
 2 1 0 2015
```

I want to:

1. Count each column where there are no "0" for year 2014. For example, for column X, the count = 2 (not 3 because I want 2014 data only). For column Y the count is 4. For column Z the count is 1.
2. Sum all the counts for each column

This is what I tried:

```
count_total <- sum(df1$x != 0 &
                   df1$y != 0 &
                   df1&z != 0 &
                   df1$Year == 2014)
count_total
```

I want the output to be simply be 1 (i.e. the 2nd row in df has no 0's)

However, this does not align with my countifs on excel. In excel, it's like this:

```
=COUNTIFS('df1'!$A$2:$A$859,"<>0",'df1'!$B$2:$B$859,"<>0",
          'df1'!$C$2:$C$859,"<>0",'df1'!$D$2:$D$859,2014)
```

Wondering if I mistyped something on R? I'm a dyplr user but can't find anything particularly useful on google.

Thank you very much!

Comment: How does your expected output 1 mean 2nd row in df has no 0's ?

Comment: To clarify, the output means that there is 1 row with no 0's.

Comment: Something like this: `colSums(d[d$Year == 2014, 1:3] != 0)`?

Comment: For the record, beware of [R FAQ 7.31](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/FAQ/R-FAQ.html#Why-doesn_0027t-R-think-these-numbers-are-equal_003f). You might need to use `sum(abs(df1$x) < 0.001, abs(df1$y) < 0.001, ...)` (or whatever mechanism you need ... the point being that it can appear that `0 != 0` when the conditions are right).

Comment: Your "I want to : " and "I want the output to be : " parts are misleading and don't agree with each other.

Comment: @RonakShah Yes, I paid atention to *'Count each **column** where there are no "0" for year 2014'*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is using `rowSums` on `subset` of data

```
sum(rowSums(subset(df1, Year == 2014) == 0) == 0)
#[1] 1
```

Comment: I believe the OP wants `colSums(. != 0)` and I don't see how the outer `sum` does anything useful.

Comment: @RuiBarradas I am confused about OP's expected output because OP said `I want the output to be simply be 1 (i.e. the 2nd row in df has no 0's)` . I might just delete this if this isn't what OP wants. PS - I am calculating number of rows which has no 0's in it.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `aggregate` then `colSums` to get the totals by column.

```
agg <- aggregate(. ~ Year, df1, function(x) sum(x != 0))
agg
#  Year X Y Z
#1 2014 2 4 2
#2 2015 1 1 0

colSums(agg[-1])
#X Y Z 
#3 5 2
```

**Data.**

```
df1 <- read.table(text = "
X Y Z Year
 0 2 4 2014
 3 1 3 2014
 5 4 0 2014
 0 3 0 2014
 2 1 0 2015
",header = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

`dplyr`approach:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  group_by(Year) %>% 
  summarise_at(vars(X:Z), function (x) sum(x != 0))
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#    Year     X     Y     Z
#   <int> <int> <int> <int>
# 1  2014     2     4     2
# 2  2015     1     1     0
```

Answer (score 2):

Alternative using `summaryBy`.

```
library(doBy)
summaryBy(list(c('X','Y','Z'), c('Year')), df1, FUN= function(x) sum(x!=0), keep.names=T)

  Year X Y Z
1 2014 2 4 2
2 2015 1 1 0
```

When needed use `colSums` as explained before.